# PHP and mysqli registration page not working

Tags: php, html, mysqli

This is a simple php code through which I want to insert into database table. But I don't know why this is not working.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Registration</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form method = "POST" action = "checkregister.php">
  <label for = "email">EmailID</label>
  <input type = "text" id = "email" name = "email" /><br />
  <label for = "pass">Password</label>
  <input type = "text" id = "pass" name = "pass" /><br />
  <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "submit" />
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

**checkregister.php**

```
  <?php
   $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'justdental')
   or die("couldn't connect");
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $pass = $_POST['pass'];

   $query = "INSERT INTO register (email, pass) VALUES ('$email', '$pass')";
   mysqli_query($conn, $query)
   or die("Not connecting");

   echo 'Registered Succesfully!';

   mysqli_close($conn);
   ?>
```

Comment: are you getting the `Registered Succesfully!`?

Comment: What do you mean by `this is not working` ???

Comment: @Saty he is not checking if it is posted or not taht is first problem in this code.

Comment: Hey am getting 'Not connecting' message.

Comment: Incidentally, you have serious SQL injection vulnerabilities in this code - don't put this live, as you will get hacked at some point. Passwords should also never be stored in plain text.

Comment: Your last edit harmed your own question, so I have rolled it back. In particular it removed some of the code formatting, so your code was not readable. Also, question titles that list question "themes" e.g. php,mysql are often regarded as attempts to insert tags into titles - and we say that tags do not belong in titles, since there is a tagging system for that. The solution is to write titles in flowing English e.g. "How to get this PHP and MySQL registration page to work?". Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the information halfer

Comment: No worries. If you have the time to take tutorials, I have my own - see my profile for a link. It shows, amongst other things, how to store passwords safely and how to avoid SQL injection. It uses PDO but the parameterisation concepts are just as valid for MySQLi.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should check if it is posted or not:

```
<?php
   $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'justdental')
   or die("couldn't connect");


if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
   exit();
 }

if (!mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM register WHERE 1=1" ) ) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
}
if(isset( $_POST['email'] )  ){
   $email = $_POST['email'];
} else{
   echo "could not get email .";
}
if( isset( $_POST['pass'] ) ){
   $pass = $_POST['pass'];
} else{
   echo 'Password could not get.';
}
if( $email && $pass ){
   $query = "INSERT INTO register ( email, pass) VALUES ('" . $email . "','" . $pass . "')";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
   if( isset($conn->insert_id) && $conn->insert_id ){
       echo 'Registered Succesfully!';
   } else {
       printf("Error: %s\n", $conn->error);
   }
} 
   mysqli_close($conn);
   ?>
```

There are a couple of serious security issues with this code, which I've not fixed to avoid confusing the issue. Firstly, the code is vulnerable to SQL injection, which is likely to result in people bypassing your credential checks if this goes live.

Also, your passwords are not hashed, and so can be read either using SQL injection vulns, or perhaps if the database can be stolen another way. That will put your users' security at risk, since people - despite the industry's advice - will often reuse passwords.

Comment: Thank you for the edited code but unfortunately it still displays the same message

Comment: @Stark can you `var_dump( $conn );` and let me know what you are getting ?

Comment: am getting this...     object(mysqli)#1 (19) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(0) ["client_info"]=> string(79) "mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 3c688b6bbc30d36af3ac34fdd4b7b5b787fe5555 $" ["client_version"]=> int(50011) ["connect_errno"]=> int(0) ["connect_error"]=> NULL ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["field_count"]=> int(0) ["host_info"]=> string(20) "localhost via TCP/IP" ["info"]=> NULL ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["server_info"]=> string(6) "5.6.26" ["server_version"]=> int(50626) ["stat"]=> stri........... Not connecting

Comment: @Stark  can you edit your question to let me know where you are using var_dump() ? you should use it just below ` $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'justdental')
   or die("couldn't connect");`

Comment: I am using var_dump() just above if( $email && $pass ) of your edited code.

Comment: is there any database named 'justdental' in your database ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96409/discussion-between-prafulla-kumar-sahu-and-stark).

Comment: @Prafulla: there is a SQL injection vulnerability in the OP's code, and thus also here too. Passwords should also not be stored in plain text. This code is not safe to use. When answering questions please do look out for this vulnerability, and at least comment if you see it - and even better still, show the OP how to fix it. (I've downvoted, but if you can fix, let me know and I will undownvote).

Comment: @halfer that is not for what the question is asked. I have worked for more tahn 2 years, I know how I should work and if you have good knowledge to understand the code the person who has posted the question is just learning and he an learn everything with I do not need to tell him, to use OOP, password encryption, stored procedure, MVC  etc etc .why you feel , I should explain everything here, The community is supposed answer question not for writing explaining like tutorials .

Comment: @halfer HEwas facing problem in just making simple query why you want him to learn everything at once ?? let him take his time and learn , the steps will never complete.

Comment: @halfer You could have edited my answer to make it better or you could have add your own answer ,how you find it is not useful and should be down voted, I do not understand it,neither I care, I know he will learn things with time and his problem is solved .

Comment: @Prafulla: it may surprise you to discover that every time the community points out the security vulns in an answer, there is often a response like yours (it's out of scope, that's too much work, etc). The result is that the OP publishes an app with basic security flaws that you could have prevented. If you do not care about that, you should. (Note that downvotes from me are not personal - they are informational messages - try not to take them personally).

Comment: @halfer if I have thought he is in a stage to learn anything extra, I would have definitely explained him about that,  I thought he should make a class with some functions , I asked him to do so,,I feel he should learn PDO, I have asked him to learn it, If he is learning he will definitely know he need to encrypt the password .

Comment: @halfer In these days I do not think programmer are facing problem of skipping password encryption during a production work, but if someone is in first stage and he do not know, It is ok, first he need to believe he can store data, he can retrieve, he can do this work, then he definitely think about betterment , It is obvious .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96431/discussion-between-prafulla-kumar-sahu-and-halfer).